# Rotate image from Camera and Gallery's image

Tags: android, image, rotation

I have a project. i want take picture use camera device and open gallery to take picture and both can show on imageview in my project. then, i want this image that in imageview can proccess, rotate. i have code to rotate, but that code done just for image was saved in drawable folder. Please help and save me. in XML any imageview (for showing image), 3 button : "take picture", "open gallery" and "rotate". How image that showing in imageview from gallery and camera can be rotate?

Comment: Can you post your code and XML ?

Comment: You'll need to use `MediaStore.Images` to get the images from Gallery. For taking pictures with the camera, use `startActivityForResult()` with the `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent-filter. You'll get back the `Bitmap` in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: @Hansjörg Hofer : can you check my code in my answer? and i hope you also can fix that. thank you....

Comment: @TimeManx : I was used that too, my problem is how rotate image that showed in imageview from gallery and camera. can you fix my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code for rotating the image is correct. But I don't understand why are you scaling the image to half.

You'd be better off by removing `matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f)` and changing

```
int newWidth = bMap.getWidth()/2;
int newHeight = bMap.getHeight()/2;
```

to

```
int newWidth = bMap.getHeight();
int newHeight = bMap.getWidth();
```

Comment: at first i used that code too, but not working. then i use code above...  i suspicious with : `ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);` i found the original code without ImageView at first code, just `imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);` but in my eclipse doesn't correct code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
private Uri mUri;
private Bitmap mPhoto;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View tombolCamera = findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
    tombolCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
    View tombolGallery = findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);
    tombolGallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    View tombolRotate = findViewById(R.id.btnRotate);
    tombolRotate.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

case R.id.btnCamera:
    Intent c = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "photo.jpg");
    c.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
    mUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    startActivityForResult(c, TAKE_PICTURE);
break;

case R.id.btnGallery:
    Intent g = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(g, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
break;

case R.id.btnRotate:
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    Bitmap bMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f);

    int newWidth = bMap.getWidth()/2;
    int newHeight = bMap.getHeight()/2;

    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, matrix, true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);

break;
    }
}

public void onActivityResult1(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(mUri, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            try {
                mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mUri);
                ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView)).setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

}
```

}
}

This is just work button "Gallery" to showing picture in imageview. But, when i am click "Rotate", the picute just freeze. Please fix my code....

Comment: Here in stackoverflow, we make all changes to the original question.